# Java: Move string literals to constant

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any way to move all the string literals from java code to Constant file? Some eclipse plugin or some workaround?

Comment: Guys if down voting please do mention the reason

Comment: You're asking for a library/plugin. I think that's the main reason.

Comment: i am not asking about library, its about idea, how it can be achieved?

Comment: Edit your post to reformulate the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, simply follow below steps:

1. Right click on src folder(folder containing java files) of project
2. Navigate to Source -> Externalize Strings..
3. Click Ok

and you are done.